# How can I track the download progress of a <a href="#" download>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to build a download progress bar ( I download the canvas content as png image [converted from base64] ) and I have a little problem : Is there a way to track the download of a :
`<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>` ?
The available events for `<a>` , from : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp
doesn't seem to help me.

I've tried to put the `<a>` tag inside a `<div>` tag and use the div's events like :

```
 <div load="alert('test1');" progress="alert('test2');" >
  <a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>
   <img src="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" alt="W3Schools" width="104" height="142">
  </a>
 </div>
```

( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOM_events )

But didn't work.

So, to sum it up, what I'm trying to achieve by this is tracking the download after a click on a `<a href="/images/myw3schoolsimage.jpg" download>` so I can build a progress bar for the download

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Did you get an error?

Comment: I didn't get any alert, I've test it on w3schools online compiler

Answer (score 0):

Those attributes you have on your `div` element aren't doing anything; if you look at the wiki page again, you'll notice that each of those events has `(none)` listed under the `Attribute` column. The solution isn't as easy as you might have in mind. It's possible this explanation could help accomplish what you're looking for though: [ajax file download : progress event, for download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041447/ajax-file-download-progress-event-for-download)

Comment: There is no ajax involved here though...

Comment: Thank you for help but I don't understand the meaning of this : `oReq.open("get", "url", true);` . This is a request but I don't need a request ,what I need is to get the canvas content and download on the user's device as a image..